# Javascript - TypeError: newString.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm attempting to accept a string (str) as input and then return that string in reverse. (right now it will return an array because I haven't converted the output to a string) My issue is that I keep getting the error TypeError: newString.push is not a function. I declared newString as an array and am attempting to push elements into it. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
    function FirstReverse(str) { 
      var newString = [ ];
      var eachLetter = str.split("");
      for(i = eachLetter.length; eachLetter.length >= 0; i - 1){
        newString =+ newString.push(eachLetter[i]);     
    }
  return newString; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`newString = + something`

The arithmetic operation will turn `newString` into a number.

You don't need to re-assign `newString` after `push` at all.

```
newString.push(eachLetter[i])   // append to newString
```

Comment: I didn't know that about the arithmetic operation. I thought it just added whatever element was next in the `eachLetter` array to `newString`.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to reverse a string:

```
"something".split("").reverse().join("")
```

To fix your problem:

- `eachLetter.length >= 0` <- this causes an infinite loop, should be `i >= 0`
- `i` you should start at `eachLetter.length - 1`, the last index
- do not reassign the `newString` array
- you should update the value of `i` if you don't want an infinite loop, `i = i - 1`
- don't return an array, join the elements to produce a string

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
   var newString = [];
   var eachLetter = str.split("");

   for (i = eachLetter.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1){
       newString.push(eachLetter[i]);     
   }

   return newString.join(""); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your explanation was the most helpful in understanding my errors. And I didn't know about the `.reverse( )`

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning (actually adding) to `newString` the result of `newResult.push()`.

About `Array.push()`, the return value is a number and it modifies the original array. ([Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push))

You also have some trouble in the (infinite) for loop..

Finally, you're returning an array, not a string.

Try this modification:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    var newString = [ ];
    var eachLetter = str.split("");
    for(i = eachLetter.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        newString.push(eachLetter[i]);
    }
    return newString.join(""); 
}
```

You can avoid using arrays:

```
function FirstReverse(str) {
    var i, rev = "";
    for(i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) rev += str[i];

    return rev;
}
```